# How to create a CXF webservice client with dynamic endpoint?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, endpoint

We have a central WSDL file that describes a web service. We use CXF to generate client code, but this code seems to be bound to 1 endpoint. How can i create a CXF client that uses the WSDL, but where I can specify the endpoint? Is there are way in changing the endpoint to a URL that implements the same WSD:?

Comment: do have any idea how to create CXF provider with dynamic endpoint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the `other` service implements the same WSDL, when you create the `MyClientService` object, you can pass the URL to the new service's WSDL right to the constructor and it will us it.  Most services would expose its wsdl on ?wsdl so using that may "just work".

Alternatively, you can override the endpoint URL via:

```
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_URL, "http://my.service.url.com/...")
```

where `proxy` is the `MyClientService` object.

Comment: The "other" service implementation indeed implements the same wsdl. I checked the generated code and i have a factory object which gives me an object. i see no way on how to specify the url sofar.. any hints on that?

Answer (score 5):

Working in cxf 2.6.1

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
client.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, "http://some-valid-endpoint") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **JaxWsProxyFactoryBean** for dynamically calling a service

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

factory.setServiceClass(ChangeStudentDetails.class);
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:8081/CXFTutorial/ChangeStudent");
```

Comment: didn't you forgot to call `factory.create()` ?

Answer (score 1):

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find wsdl:binding operation info for web method XXXX.
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:125)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.getUser(Unknown Source)

If this error occurred then add annotation Webservice to your client side interface which is already developed on service side.

I faced this issue, I have configured Spring with CXF. I have already developed the service and calling it from client.

Hope this will help.