# Exchangeable targetnamespace in Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, wsdl

I want dynamically exchange the webserive targetnamescpace (host) in the cade generated by Apache CXF.

Why? Each customer has its own wsdl file.

The current situation is that there is one project, that depends on wsdl X that is hosted on serverX. That means for each Customer an extra build with he specific wsdl URL.
The wsdl files are always identically, just the server changes.

A fat jar (jar-with-dependencies) will be build and uploaded to our nexus server.

We use Java 7 and Maven 3 to build our projects.

The problem is when deploying to nexus you cannot change the change the name of the artifact that gets deployed. application-1.0-CUSTOMER.jar would be a nice pattern but i didn't found a way to solve that and also the whole process dosen't seem very clean.

The webservice-.java files gets generated by the cxf-codegen-plugin plugin. I am using this configuration:

```
<!-- CXF wsdl2Java Generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf/</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>
                                    http://trunk. ....
                                </wsdl>
                                <serviceName>ServiceName</serviceName>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    <!-- override the namespace to have always identical package names -->
                                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>de.packagename.wsdl</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here one of the generated java files:

```
/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.7.0
 * 2013-11-13T14:35:21.046+01:00
 * Generated source version: 2.7.0
 * 
 */
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://trunk...", name = "SomeName")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface SomeName {
...
}
```

My idea was to cut out the whole webservice-client implementation out of that application and put it in another project (one project one customer) -- but how to call the webservice from the original project? Currently one Interface is used by the original project as well as one model class.

---

I know that there is a hack around the deployment problem by using a artifact version with a variable, but it is highly discouraged, at least in maven 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it.
Its similar to this one: [How to create a CXF webservice client with dynamic endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447464/how-to-create-a-cxf-webservice-client-with-dynamic-endpoint) but only after a half day debugging i found my solution.

```
    final QName qname = new QName(Settings.MAIN_SCAN_SERVICE_SOAP_URL.get().toString(), "PortName");
    final String wsdlUrl = Settings.MAIN_SCAN_SERVICE_WSDL_URL.get().toString();

    final JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(Settings.MAIN_SCAN_SERVICE_SOAP_URL.get().toString());
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setEndpointName(qname);
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceName(new QName(wsdlUrl, "PortName"));
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setWsdlLocation(wsdlUrl);
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(PortImpl.class);
    this.portImpl = (PortImpl) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();
```